# Identification of component marked "UJ"

Tags: transistors, identification

[image]

This component is near a coil, some capacitors and I think a diode of some kind.
I would be grateful if anyone could identify and provide a suitable part number, I have looked on databases without success.

Comment: Did you tag this with "transistors" because you think it is a transistor?

Comment: From the surroundings it sounds like a switch mode voltage converter, but without any more information this is going to be quite tough.

Comment: For me it looks like a FET with a pinout like e.g. PMN55ENEAX. @rdtsc pin 1 is bottom left, 3 = gate

Comment: I have limited knowledge, I wasn't sure if it was transistor. Thanks for replies, I shall investigate PMN55ENEAX. Thanks again everyone.

Comment: Wider picture useful showing what is nearby.